# adding offset to elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have the following code:

```
 $pictureQuery = new \Elastica\Query\MultiMatch();
            $pictureQuery->setParam('query', $queryString);
            $pictureQuery->setType('phrase_prefix');
            $pictureQuery->setParam('fields', array(
                'caption'
            ));

            $filtered = new \Elastica\Query\Filtered($pictureQuery, new \Elastica\Filter\Missing('deletedAt'));
            $elasticaQuery = \Elastica\Query::create($filtered);
            $elasticaQuery->setLimit($limit);
            $pictures = $itemFinder->find($elasticaQuery);
```

I wanted to have offset in this query. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the **From** and **Size** (Elasticsearch API) parameters.  I'm not familiar with FOSElasticaBundle but [this question demonstrates the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718211/foselasticabundle-customscore-query-pagination).